# Fetching webpages from localhost

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, wamp

Is it possible to make a jQuery request to get a webpage if this request originates from localhost? I am currently using wamp server and get the message XMLHttpRequest cannot load <url>. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: if you control the endpoint you can implement CORS on endpoint, otherwise use a script on your localhost as proxy to get the data using cURL

Answer (score 1):

On apache :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Or on php :

Check here : [Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)